# webdriver.Chrome ERRNO 10054

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have some web scraping script but now it doesn't work. I get an error on just these lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I get:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I tried to reinstall Chrome, use last version of chromedriver but it still doesn't work.
Could somebody help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--screen-size=1920X1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('your_chrome_patch/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: add explanation to your solution